# Template in document library

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, document-library, document-template

How to change Document template from word template to Web Part Page in doc library ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I understand from you. you need to set the default new document file to be `web part page Template` instead of `Word Template`

If this what you need follow these steps :

- Create a new dummy document library with your selected template `Web part Page`

[image]

- From the above ribbon of document library > Select Open with explorer.
- Copy the file with name `_webpartpage.htm`
- Go back to your main document library > Select Open with explorer > paste this file `_webpartpage.htm`
- Now go back to the main document library list setting > advanced setting > then set the Template URL to `your_docuemnt_library_name/Forms/_webpartpage.htm`
- Go back to add a new document from the ribbon. that should be listed as the following

[image]

- Delete the dummy document library that you created before.